# Join с подзапросом

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Помогите составить запрос, который выводит список транзакций, превысившие определенный месячный лимит. Существует банковская система, где клиент может совершать транзакции и устанавливать лимит на свой аккаунт. Также клиент может сам устанавливать себе лимит, пример:
01.01.2023 клиент установил лимит в 1000руб. 02.01.2023 совершил транзакцию на 900руб, остаток лимита составляет 100руб, 03.01.2023 совершает транзакцию на 500руб, остаток лимита равен -400, соответственно лимит превышен(limit_exceed = true). 10.01.2023 клиент устанавливает лимит в 2000руб, остаток лимита = 1600, лимит не превышен.
Попробовал решить задачу с помощью join'a с подзапросом и агрегирующей функцией, но не могу грамотно составить. Прошу помощи. Пример своей запроса и ERD прикладываю.

```
select
    *
from
    solva.transactions t
left join solva.limits l (
    select
        max(l.setting_date)
    from
        solva.limits l2
    where
        l2.setting_date <= t.date_time
    group by
        t.id,
        l.id,
        t.date_time,
        t.account_from,
        t.date_time) on
    l.user_account = t.account_from
where
    t.limit_exceeded = true
    and t.account_from = l.user_account
    and t.date_time between :startdate and :enddate;
```

[image: ERD]

Comment: Тут нужна не агрегирующая функция, а её оконная версия.

Comment: Что-то странно. Был месячный лимит 1000, потом 2000, но остаток (1600) как будто месячный лимит 3000. Получается, при модификации клиент не устанавливает месячный лимит, а инкрементального его увеличивает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать привязку действующего лимита к дате транзакции так:

```
select *
from solva.transactions tsolva.transactions t 
left join(
  select *
    ,lead(setting_date,1,current_date)
        over(partition by user_account order by setting_date) 
    - interval 'days 1' to_date
   from limits 
 ) l on l.user_account = t.account_from
    and t.date_time between l.setting_date and l.to_date
where
    t.limit_exceeded = true
--теперь не нужно    and t.account_from = l.user_account
    and t.date_time between :startdate and :enddate;
```

Здесь в качестве срока действия последнего лимита указано current_date. Можно поставить что-то иное, подходящее по смыслу задачи. Сравнение времени с датами надо дополнительно проверить.
Что-же касается превышения лимита, по пояснению к вопросу не понятно, с какой даты считаются транзакции. Возможно, с даты первой установки лимита. Но гадать не буду. Можете посчитать накопленные транзакции оконной функцией, как советовал @Akina.